# Can i know why the title and modified by not showing also the box shadow was also not working... sorry im new with this

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, view-formatting

Can I know why the title and modified by not showing? also the box shadow is not working?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": "120",
  "width": "400",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "background-color": "white",
      "box-shadow": "0 3px 10px white",
      "display": "flex",
      "position": "relative",
      "font-size": "0.8rem"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
              "target": "_blank",
              "href": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534796636912-3b95b3ab5986?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "filepreview",
                "style": {
                  "width": "150px",
                  "height": "120px"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "src": "@thumbnail.512x432",
                  "alt": "Image"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "font-weight": "bold",
              "padding": "15px"
            },
            "txtContent": "Hai [$Name]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "color": "RGBA(155, 155, 155, 1)",
              "position": "absolute",
              "bottom": "0",
              "padding": "15px"
            },
            "txtContent": "Uploaded on [$Modified]"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly add statis text (like 'Hai') and dynamic content from SharePoint column in `txtContent`. You have to write the expression to combine these like:

```
"txtContent": "='Hai ' + [$Name]"
```

**Full example**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "height": "120",
  "width": "400",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "formatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "style": {
      "background-color": "white",
      "box-shadow": "0 3px 10px white",
      "display": "flex",
      "position": "relative",
      "font-size": "0.8rem"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "a",
            "attributes": {
              "target": "_blank",
              "href": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534796636912-3b95b3ab5986?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8MXx8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "filepreview",
                "style": {
                  "width": "150px",
                  "height": "120px"
                },
                "attributes": {
                  "src": "@thumbnail.512x432",
                  "alt": "Image"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "font-weight": "bold",
              "padding": "15px"
            },
            "txtContent": "='Hai ' + [$Name]"
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "color": "RGBA(155, 155, 155, 1)",
              "position": "absolute",
              "bottom": "0",
              "padding": "15px"
            },
            "txtContent": "='Uploaded on ' + toLocaleDateString([$Modified])"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Note**: Make sure columns you are using in JSON (like Name, Modified, etc.) are included/shown in list view. This is required for JSON formatting in SharePoint.